Android Studio - Gradle sync failing, java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger
I'm working on schedule reminder feature for my app which requires push notifications to be sent to the device after a specific amount of time. Because I'm using an emulator to test this (Medium Phone API 35, which supports Google Play), the push notifications won't appear. I recently found out that the reason the Android emulator won't receive push notifications is because Google Play services weren't enabled. So I installed the Google Play Services tool in the SDK manager and added the following lines under Dependencies in my build.gradle.kts file:
implementation(libs.appcompat.v7) implementation(libs.play.services) 
I also added the following lines under Application in the AndroidManifest.xml file:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
Once I saved and tried syncing the project, I ended up getting a bunch of errors:
***Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
[com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0] C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-4\0e5194e9679647097272aa5d6a2103e9\transformed\animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'android.support.graphics.drawable' is used in multiple modules and/or libraries: com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0, com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0. Please ensure that all modules and libraries have a unique namespace. For more information, See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
[com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:12.0.1] C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-4\fbf92b861eb908bad9ec537dbb7caa90\transformed\play-services-tagmanager-12.0.1\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'com.google.android.gms.tagmanager' is used in multiple modules and/or libraries: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:12.0.1, com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:12.0.1. Please ensure that all modules and libraries have a unique namespace. For more information, See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
[androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1] C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-4\7683fc3f03d19717ececca26267bd245\transformed\versionedparcelable-1.1.1\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
Namespace 'androidx.versionedparcelable' is used in multiple modules and/or libraries: androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1, com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0. Please ensure that all modules and libraries have a unique namespace. For more information, See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-43:19 Error:
tools:replace specified at line:8 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
Validation failed, exiting

See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.***
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ui.screens.DetailActivity" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>

And here is what my build.gradle.kts file looks like:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.adk224_tm470_project"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.adk224_tm470_project"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    viewBinding {
        enable = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }

    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.android)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.splashscreen)

    implementation(libs.glide)
    annotationProcessor(libs.compiler)

    implementation(libs.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.material.material)
    implementation(libs.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose.v260)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose.v172)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx.v262)

    implementation(libs.androidx.work.runtime.ktx)

    implementation(libs.appcompat.v7)
    implementation(libs.play.services)

}

I've tried checking the Merged Manifest tab in the AndroidManifest.xml file and there's an error saying "Merge Errors Error: tools:replace specified at line:8 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified adk224_TM470_Project.app main manifest (this file), line 7"
This is all very overwhelming, so if anyone who has experience on this matter, let me know what I can do to fix all this, because I can't continue my app without testing to see if my app can send push notifications to the emulator.
